# How to use jms.Connection.setExceptionListner to release resources and reconnect?

Tags: java, exception, singleton, connection, jms

Assuming I have one `Connection` per JVM (implemented as a singleton) as a derivative of the docs which recommend having one `Connection` as it's a heavy object.

**From the docs:**

> ... a connection is a relatively
>   heavyweight object. Most clients will
>   do all their messaging with a single
>   connection... A JMS client
>   typically creates a connection, one or
>   more sessions, and a number of message
>   producers and consumers.

I'm trying to decide what to do with my `Sessions`, `Producers` and `Consumers` with respect to the `ExceptionListener` which is at the `Connection` level.
To the best of my understanding it is very reasonable they are no longer usable, when a `JMSException` is thrown, but I'm not sure what should be done once the above listener is triggered.
My `Sessions` are kept in a `ThreadLocal<Session>` which is also kept in a singleton.
I can use this to call `MySessionSingleton.closeSession()` in the listener but this will only close the `Session` which is bound to the thread in which  the Exception was thrown and not all other `Sessions`.
In addition this does not take care of the Producers\Consumers and their reconnect.
A possible solution which I saw used and I'm reluctant to imitate is to have a Connection and a Session for every Producer\Consumer and so I can control all of the above.

Would appreciate any thoughts,
Ittai
**Clarification:**
My current implementation, by a former programmer, is the one I refer to above as being used and the biggest problem it poses for me is that I need several producers and consumers to use the same `Session` as I have a need for JTA transactions and I think (might be wrong) that I need those Producers\Consumers to share the session.
The connection was a derivative of that decision.
So basically even if I keep the relationship of one session per connection I still have the above problem when one session has multiple Producers\Consumers.

Comment: Hmm, can you show us some source code?  Might be easier to understand the structure

Comment: Of the current code? Or what I'm trying to acheive?

Comment: Both - It would be good to see the original as well to try and understand what the original developer was trying to do (having Session stored in ThreadLocal seems odd to me for example)

Answer (score 0):

I still don't see why you need to only have one Connection object :-).  I'd let the application server (I assume you're running in one) take care of managing the Connection resources for you.

i.e.  Use a ConnectionFactory in order to get your Connections and create your session and consumers and producers off that.

Something roughly like:

```
public void notify(String errorOccurrence)
{
    Connection connection = null;

    try
    {
        connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();

        Session session = connection.createSession(true, 
                          javax.jms.Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(errorOccurrence);

        MessageProducer messageProducer = 
                            session.createProducer(errorOccurrenceChannel);

        messageProducer.send(message);
    }
    catch (JMSException e)
    {
        handleJmsExcption(e);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (connection != null)
        {
            try
            {
                connection.close();
            }
            catch (JMSException e)
            {
                handleJmsExcption(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @karianna I updated my question to better explain the need. Thanks.

Comment: @karianna I did forget to mention I'm not running in an app server due to various reasons not up to me. We're currently using atomikos as the transaction manager and openmq as the JMS provider.

Comment: Ah interesting, OK - I'll give this another shot :-)

Comment: @lttai Does OpenMQ come with a ConnectionFactory, I would've thought that it did.

Comment: @karianna Yes OpenMQ has a JMS ConnectionFactory implementation (at least in 4.4 which is the first version I worked with)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a naive question as I have not much real world experience with JMS, but wouldn't it be the easiest way to call connection.close()?

The JMS API says that "There is no need to close the sessions, producers, and consumers of a closed connection."

Aditionally a global flag could be set as a signal for message handler loops etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I fear that the API is not accurate in that aspect as I saw several references which state it is important to call close(). In addition your "global flag" idea gave me an idea to use the Publish-Subscribe design pattern where each new Producer/Consumer register with a session and all sessions register with a connection and so I can trigger the Reconnect sequence.

Comment: @lttai - I think @mjustin is correct, I have personally not seen any issues when calling close() on a Connection

Comment: @karianna The main problem is that I need the producers/consumers to reconnect. That's why I think the Publish-Subscribe pattern might work for me.

Comment: @lttai - If you close the Connection then in order to reconnect you're going to have to open a fresh Connection.  In your case since you have a singleton, you're going to have to re-initialise it, so in your exception handling you'll need to call out to something in order to recreate